# AppX Installation Failed with errror message "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: windows-10-universal, msdn, appx, makeappx

I have created appx using MakeAppx tool. During sideloading, i am getting below error.[image: AppxInstallationFailed]

I knew Windows Apps are gets installed at location "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps"
and normal user won't have ownership for this folder.

[image]Does I need to change the ownership for "WindowsApps" folder?Looking for the solution to this problem as we can't expect from user to change the ownership to install appx.

Comment: This should not be caused by capabilities, could you please package your app with Visual Studio and test again? And compare with the vs packaged with make-appx packaged to see if you missed anything when you creating the appx?

Comment: @Sunteen,I have win32 application which can't be packaged using visual studio..That is why I have used makeappx tool to convert win 32 application  to appx.Also I don't think anything was missing  while creating aapx as package was created successfully using makeappx tool.Also interesting to mention that on some system this installation succeeded but on some failed with above error mainly on RS3 machines.

Comment: @Sunteen,Also I would like to mention package passing WACK test even.Now this issue is becoming blocker for us

Comment: Today i have found this problem comes  all store apps when internet is disconnected and we try to install on RS3 machine.When internet is connected,appx installed successfully.But i want to install it when internet is discoonected by double clicking on appx.

Comment: Did you mean the app can be installed on previously OS successfully with internet connected? Did your app use the desktop bridge?

Comment: @Sunteen,the app using desktop bridge.For RS2,build version 15063,i am able to install same appx without internet.But for RS3,build version 16299,i observed internet is required to install same appx or any appx.

Comment: Today by just turning off the windows defender smartscreen security  in RS3 machines,appx gets installed succefully without internet which  i want.So marking this as resolution.Thankz for input@Sunteen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today by just turning off the windows defender smartscreen security in RS3 machines,appx gets installed succefully without internet which i want.So marking this as resolution.Thankz for input@Sunteen